# How to use a custom constructor when using ProjectTo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, automapper

being somehow new to Automapper, I've got a question about projectTo method.

Here is some background :

I'm fetching Addresses object linked to accounts or users.

I then want to project them into a list of Addresses tagged with the type.

```
IQueryable<AddressTagged> q1 = _users.Query()
            .Select(x => x.Address)
            .ProjectTo<AddressTagged>();

IQueryable<AddressTagged> q2 = _accounts.Query()
            .Select(x => x.Adress)
            .ProjectTo<AddressTagged>();
```

AddressTagged has the same members than Address plus an AddressType which is an enum (either account or user).

How could I change the call of projectTo to set AddressType to the appropriate value ?

Thank you for reading and for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ConstructProjectionUsing. [An example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Projection/ConstructorTests.cs).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't get how I can use this correctly.  
  
In the sample :   
                `cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
.ConstructProjectionUsing(src => new Dest(src.Value + 10));`
  
How can I get this "+ 10" a parameter when projecting : 
  `_dest = values.ProjectTo<Dest>(Configuration).ToArray();`
  ?

Comment: Well, that's a different question :) As is usually the case, the answer is in the [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#parameterization).